# SQL Server beginner questions

Tags: sql-server, select

I'm new to SQL Server and have a test coming next week and I have some questions.

If I want to select a column, eg. country name which contains the letter n, do I write it as

```
select countryname
from <table name> 
where country name like '%n%', %n', 'n%';
```

and if I need to find a column eg. country name which start with the letter c OR end with the letter y , do I phase it as

```
select countryname
from <tablename>
where countryname like 'y%' and countryname like '%y'
```

Any help would be appreciated!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> okay, if I want to select a column, eg. country name which contains
>   the letter n, do I write it as select countryname from where country
>   name like '%n%' , %n' , 'n%' ;

For this you need to write `LIKE '%n%'`

`LIKE  '%n'`Finds any country that ends with "n"

`LIKE 'n%'` Finds any country that starts with "n"

> and if I need to find a column eg. country name which start with the
>   letter c OR end with the letter y , do I phase it as select
>   countryname from where countryname like 'y%' and countryname like '%y'

For this you need to write `countryname LIKE 'c%' OR countryname LIKE '%y'`

I suggest you to please read the article [SQL Server: LIKE Condition](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/like.php)